# Django ORM When check

Tags: django, django-orm

I would like to make a query to know whether particular user has relation with specific object.
As for example:

```
user = User.objects.first()
modelA.objects.annotate(has_user=Case(When( XXXXXX, 
     then=Value(True)), default=Value(False), output_field=BooleanField())))
```

XXXX should be replaced with code which checks whether `model_b_set.values_list('user', flat=True)` contains given user.

**UPDATED**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model_a_set')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modelA = models.ForeignKey('models_a.ModelA', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model_b_set')
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model_b_set')
```

User model is custom but it will not reflect on other models
Also updated example of code in order to fit to my example models

Comment: What Django version are you using? Looks to me an exist is more appropriate here.

Comment: It would be helpful if u add your model details.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Django 2.1.2

Comment: @SusajSNair What details do you need?

Comment: @Ernst: I think it might be good to share the relation between `ModelA` and `User`, and if you constructed a custom `User` model, share the relevant model details as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated

Comment: XXXX maybe like this : model_b_set__user_id__isnull=False

Comment: @NgocPham I need to check whether random user exists in set of model_b_set__user

Comment: @Ernst random user mean you have user_id of this user ?.

Comment: @NgocPham I got this user from `request`

Comment: then XXXX maybe change abit : model_b_set__user_id=user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better here to use an [**`Exists`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) with a subquery, like:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

modelA.objects.annotate(
    is_following_by_user=Exists(
        ModelB.objects.filter(user=my_user, modelA=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
)
```

Here we thus check per `ModelA` ojbect if there exists a `ModelB` for which `user` is `my_user`, and `modelA` is the primary key of that `ModelA` object.